# Django DetailView filter by two parameters not using the primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I need to filter a model by two values that none of them is the PK of the model.

I want to filter the payments for an specific car and week, this means that I can have more than one payment for a car and in a week.

*I'm using Django-Tables2 to display the results.*

> views.py

```
class PagosDetailView(SingleTableMixin, DetailView):

    template_name = "AC/paymentsbycarandweek.html"
    context_table_name = 'table'
    model = Pagos
    table_class = PagosTable
    slug_url_kwarg = 'carro_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PagosDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(carro=self.kwargs['carro'], semana=self.kwargs['semana'])
```

> models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):

    carro = models.ForeignKey(
        Carros, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    pago = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    fecha = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    semana = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    startweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    endweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    renta = models.ForeignKey(
        Renta, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Pagos"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pagos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.semana
```

> urls.py

```
path('paymentsbycarandweek/<int:carro>/<slug:semana>',
         views.PagosDetailView.as_view(), name='pagos_bycar')
```

This last time that I have tried several options, I'm getting the following error message:

*Generic detail view PagosDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.*

How exactly can I pass these two parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, this is how I finally resolved it:

```
class PagosDetailView(SingleTableMixin, ListView):

    model = Pagos
    table_class = PagosDetailTable
    template_name = 'AC/paymentsbycarandweek.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(
            carro=kwargs['carro'], semana=kwargs['semana'])

        context = self.get_context_data()
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```